# Vuejs import component in another component

Tags: vue.js, import, components

I created a dashboard.vue component and I imported table.vue component into it but the table.vue doesn't appear in my web page and in the vue.dev tools.

When I import the table.vue in app.vue there's no issue.

Below my files.

Thanks in advance!

//dashboard.vue

```
<template>
  <div>

  <table></table>

  </div>
</template>

<script>


import table from "./table";

 export default {
  name: 'Dashboard',
  component: {
    table, 
  }

}
</script>


<style >

</style>
```

//table.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
      <p>Test</p>

  </div>
</template>

<script>





export default {
  name: 'Table',

}
  </script>
```

Comment: Welcome, can you upload your code on here: https://codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot name components the same as reserved HTML elements. Change it to `my-table`.

You'll need to map it:

```
components: {
    'my-table': table, 
  }
```

Comment: I replaced all table by mytable and I get

Comment: Unknown custom element: <mytable> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Dashboard> at src/components/Dashboard.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>

Comment: when I import it in the app.vue there's no issue with both "table" and 'mytable"

Comment: shouldn't it be "components" not "component"?